# link gives back nil and crashes my app when using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to get JSON from URL

Tags: json, swift, url, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm new to making requests online. I'm using Alamofire and swiftyJSON to get back the data from a URL, but it keeps on crashing, saying the link is giving back nil. Is it because the provided link isn't .json at the end? (btw the link i added is fake, can't add the real one, but the structure is the same).

```
let URL = "https://www.thisurlisntreal.com/api/folder?key="12345FGhbfdgn3456fgdnf2345redfs?56"
        Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

The link just has this data:

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"fromDate":"2015-03-18","toDate":"2016-04-23","url":"blabliebloe","producer":{"id":1,"name":"theproducer"}}]}
```

I get a crash at `Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { response in` telling me `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I checked the JSON with multiple formatters and validators, and it's all succesfull, so that is not the issue.

**UPDATE:**
I just used a different link (http://refine.taxonomics.org/gbifchecklists/reconcile?query=Crepidomanes%20minutum) and this does work... I don't know how it's possible, but can it be something server-side related?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the switch satement like this:

```
switch response.result {
                case .Success(let data):
                    let json = JSON(data)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription())
                }
```

Comment: Tried it, but the app already crashes at  `Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON`, saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check that your URLRequest is set properly to expect a json answer with one of those lines:

```
mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```